# unused arguments when trying to create a matrix in R

Tags: r

I want create such matrix

```
dat <- matrix(
  "an_no" = c(14, 17), 
  "an_yes" = c(3, 1),
  row.names = c("TL-MCT-t", "ops"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

but i get error `unused arguments`.
What i did wrong and how perform correct matrix with such arguments?
`as.matrix` didn't help.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you really want a matrix, or a dataframe? If the latter, you can just replace the word `matrix` with `data.frame` and it will work.

Comment: Maybe you want: `matrix(c(14, 17, 3, 1), 2, dimnames = list(c("TL-MCT-t", "ops"),  c("an_no", "an_yes")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the arguments that you would use to build a data frame. If you want a matrix using this syntax you can do:

```r
dat <- as.matrix(data.frame(
  an_no = c(14, 17), 
  an_yes = c(3, 1),
  row.names = c("TL-MCT-t", "ops")))

dat
#>          an_no an_yes
#> TL-MCT-t    14      3
#> ops         17      1
```

You don't need the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` because none of your data elements are strings, and in any case, `stringsAsFactors` is `FALSE` by default unless you are using an old version of R. You also don't need quotation marks around `an_no` and `an_yes` because these are both legal variable names in R.

Answer (score 1):

The `matrix` function estructure is this:

```
matrix(data = NA, 
       nrow = 1,
       ncol = 1, 
       byrow = FALSE,
       dimnames = NULL)
```

Appears you're trying to create a data.frame

```
data.frame(row_names = c("TL-MCT-t", "ops"),
           an_no = c(14,17),
           an_yes = c(3,1)
)
```